# Who creates /etc/ssl/cert.pem in MacOs

Tags: macos, keychain, certificate

While using curl in verbose mode, I noticed the following line in the output:

```
 * successfully set certificate verify locations:
 *   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
 *
```

I googled and found out that `etc/ssl/cert.pem` is the CA bundle.

The question I now have is who creates this file? Running `ls -lh` I could see the file was created on Jan  1  2020, but I have been using this Mac Since 2018!

So I am really not sure how this file is managed: How it was added and how it get's updated. Any ideas?